# How do I add a JPA based PropertySource to external configuration in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration, spring-data-jpa

I've been trying to add a custom `PropertySource` to the spring `Environment` bean but cannot get it to work. I have a Spring boot application and have managed to do the following

```
@Bean
public Environment environment() {
    ConfigurableEnvironment environment = new StandardServletEnvironment();
    MutablePropertySources propertySources = environment.getPropertySources();  
    propertySources.addFirst(new DatabasePropertySource("databaseProperties"));
    return environment;
}
```

---

```
public class DatabasePropertySource extends PropertySource<DatabaseReaderDelegate> {

    public DatabasePropertySource(String name) {
        super(name, new DatabaseReaderDelegate());
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(String name) {
        return this.source.getProperty(name);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class DatabaseReaderDelegate {

    @Autowired ConfigurationDao dao;

    public Object getProperty(String property) {
        Configuration object = dao.findOneByConfKey(property);
        Object value = object.getConfValue();
        return value;
    }
}
```

---

```
public interface ConfigurationDao extends JpaRepository<Configuration, Long> {
    Configuration findOneByConfKey(String name);
}
```

This definitely adds a `DatabasePropertySource` to the `StandardServletEnvironment` but there isn't any data as the `ConfigurationDao` that is `@Autowired` is null. I have wired in the `ConfigurationDao` elsewhere and it does work and data is accessible through it. I just think it is a matter of timing during startup but I'm not sure exactly how to order/time it. Has anyone done something similar and have any help to offer to make this happen.

Answer (score 1):

Getting JPA to start up in time to include it in the `Environment` is probably impossible (it's chicken and egg). One way to break the cycle is to initialize your database and repository in a parent context, and then use it in the `Environment` of the child (your main application context). There are convenience methods for building parent and child contexts in `SpringApplicationBuilder`.

Comment: Sigh, all that work just for configuration from database. This makes the lazy developer in me cringe :(

Comment: Lazy is good. It's a boiler plate pattern so maybe it ought to be in Spring Boot (it's easy to raise issues in github, and almost as easy to send pull requests).